# How can I get the name of creating or editing software in EXIF/Metadata of an image?

Tags: php, image, metadata, exif

I try to get the name of the software which is used to create or edit an image (jpg, png, tif) by using PHP exif_read_data.
I installed php exif extension and imagemagick on server, but I can get only standard exif metadata with the following code.
My code:

```
$fimage = 'fig1-rvs.jpg';
$exif = exif_read_data($fimage, 0, true);
foreach ($exif as $key => $section){
    foreach ($section as $name => $val){
        $valm = $val;
        if ($name == "FileDateTime"){ $valm = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $val); }
        if ($name == "FileSize"){ $valm = myfilesize($val); }
        if ($name == "FileType"){ $valm = $imgtyp[$val]; }
        if ($name == "BitsPerSample"){
            $valm = "";
            foreach ($val as $keybps => $sectionbps){
                $valm .= $keybps.": ".$sectionbps."<br>";
            }
        }
        echo "[".$key."] ".$name.": ".$valm."<br>";
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
[FILE] FileName: fig1-rvs.jpg
[FILE] FileDateTime: 2023-04-13 09:26:25
[FILE] FileSize: 4.55M
[FILE] FileType: JPEG
[FILE] MimeType: image/jpeg
[FILE] SectionsFound: 
[COMPUTED] html: width="3120" height="3120"
[COMPUTED] Height: 3120
[COMPUTED] Width: 3120
[COMPUTED] IsColor: 1
```

Is there a way to get the name of creating or editing software in EXIF/Metadata of an image by using PHP?

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageproperty.php

Comment: The location for the software name in EXIF is the `Software` tag.  There are corresponding tags in both IPTC IIM and XMP.  If I recall correctly, `exif_read_data` only reads EXIF data, not data in these other groups.  Additionally, there is no guarantee that the editing software placed its name in the file or the possibility of its removal.  For example, social media (FB/Instagram) will strip away any metadata and remove the name of the editing program.

Comment: Yes, Software tag is what I am looking for. As you said, it is available in some of the images. Thanks.